# VueJS - Fire a method in a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Okay...

In VueJS i'm running a v-for to list a couple of items.
For example:

```
v-for="item in cart"

Bananas - 1 dollar - Yellow
Apples - 2 dollar - Pink
Grapes - 1.5 dollar - Green
```

While listing those items, each item has a textbox, where I can enter a note.
The problem is, I don't want to save this note in the item's object in the cart. I want to save those notes in another Vue dataobject (notes). It would be great to keep a reference to the original item, but it's not necessary.

I thought it would be nice to make this possible with a method. But I wan't this method to run on each generated listitem. So my question:

How to automatically trigger a Vue method while running a v-for loop? (Without i.e. @click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer your specific question (how to trigger a method) ... but you might be able to solve your problem using databinding.

Javascript

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        cart: [
            { name: 'banana', color: 'yellow'},
            { name: 'apple', color: 'red'},
            { name: 'lime', color: 'green'},
        ],
        notes: []
    }
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="item in cart">
      {{ item.name }} - {{ item.color }}<br/>
      <input type="text" v-model="notes[$index]"/>
    </div>

    <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Or, if you want your `notes` to be an object, you can change the `input` to this:

```
<input type="text" v-model="notes[item.name]"/>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uw25gaf6/1/).